# Measurable functions and $\sigma$-algebras generated by a collection of subsets.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma_X)$ be a measurable space. Let $Y$ be a set and $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of subsets of $Y$. Consider the measurable space $(Y,\Sigma_Y)$ where $\Sigma_Y=\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ and consider a function $f:X\to Y$. What is are (minimal) sufficient conditions on the collection $\mathcal{S}$ so that the following holds
$$f^{-1}(E)\in\Sigma_X,\;\forall E\in\mathcal{S}\implies f^{-1}(E)\in\Sigma_X,\;\forall E\in\Sigma_Y.\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$

For example, for $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{S}=\{(-\infty,b]:b\in\mathbb{R}\}$, and $\Sigma_X=\Sigma_Y=\sigma(\mathcal{S})$, we have that (*) actually holds. What is special about $\mathcal{S}$ in this case? What conditions did it satisfy so that $(*)$ holds? And how far can the argument used here be generalized?

Comment: Perhaps first (try to) write down an example where $(*)$ fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma(\mathcal S)=\Sigma_Y$ is already sufficient. In fact, the family $U=\{A\in\mathcal P(Y)\,:\,f^{-1}[A]\in \Sigma_X\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra:

- $\emptyset\in U$
- if $A\in U$, then $f^{-1}[Y\setminus A]=X\setminus f^{-1}[A]\in \Sigma_X$
- if $A_n\in U$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then $f^{-1}\left[\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\right]=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f^{-1}[A_n]\in \Sigma_X$.

And therefore $U\supseteq \sigma(\mathcal S)$.

Comment: Why is $U\subseteq \Sigma_Y$?

Comment: @UserA In the first review of the post, I had defined $U=\{A\in\Sigma_Y\,:\, f^{-1}[A]\in\Sigma_X\}$, and therefore $U\subseteq \Sigma_Y$ was for free. Anyways, I've edited it because I eventualy turned to preferring to prove the analogous lemma for $U=\{A\in\mathcal P(Y)\,:\, f^{-1}[A]\in \Sigma_X\}$. I don't know exactly which one is better, but the gig should be clear by now.